# Google Material's ExpansionPanel for ReactJS not expanding by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am building a ReactJS app using Google's Material-UI.

I have the following child class that is displayed in a Grid, after a search has been submitted. Depending if the search is one type or another, the ExpansionPanel inside this child class should be expanded or not expanded.

Here is the class that is being mapped in the parent component:

The expandByDefault boolean is passed from the parent class.

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {
    render () {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { batchAndContents } = this.props;
        const { expandByDefault } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <ExpansionPanel defaultExpanded={expandByDefault} >
                    <ExpansionPanelSummary>
                    <Typography className={classes.heading}>Box {batchAndContents.sequenceCode}</Typography>
                    </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                    <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                        <SearchResultsTable contents={batchAndContents.contents}/>
                    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                </ExpansionPanel>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the render method for the parent class:
You can see in SearchResults, my custom class, I pass a prop named expandByDefault.

```
render () {
        return (
            <div>
              . . . . .
              . . . . .
              . . . . .
              <Grid container spacing={24} style={{padding: 24}}>
                {this.state.searchResults.map((searchResult) => (
                    <Grid item key={searchResult.sequenceCode+searchResult.state}  xs={12}>
                        <SearchResults batchAndContents={searchResult} expandByDefault={this.state.lastSearchType === "ContentBarcode"}/>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I've tried several variations to get this to work, and I can't seem to understand what I'm missing.

What's interesting is that when I initially perform a search, and the ExpansionPanel's property defaultExpanded is set to true, it works. However if I don't refresh the page and perform another search with a different type, the results don't collapse back down when the type should cause that behavior.

Same behavior occurs if I initially perform the search and the ExpansionPanel defaultExpanded is set to false. It expands on click, and is default collapsed, however, when changing the search type to something that should cause default expanded panels, it doesn't work.

I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You want `expanded`, not `defaultExpanded`.

Comment: @Herohtar Thanks for your reply, that actually wasn't the issue, I posted my solution down below. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. The property only seems to look at the value in the initial rendering.

If it's undefined or has a default value in the initial rendering then it will be used even when the value of`this.props.expandByDefault` is changed; its simply ignored.

You have to avoid rendering the component altogether until the prop has received the "correct" value if you want to use this feature.

It seems odd at first but it makes sense when you think about it. Once initially rendered the API doesn't want to risk overwriting actions taken by the user and accidentally close or open the dialog against one's will. It would probably lock the panel.

Answer (score 0):

The `defaultExpanded` property only defines the *default* state of the component -- ie, whether or not to expand the panel when it is first rendered. Changes to this value later will not affect whether the panel is currently expanded or not.

To cause the panel to expand or collapse in response to changes in your app, you need to use the `expanded` property. From the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/expansion-panel/):

> If `true`, expands the panel, otherwise collapse it. Setting this prop enables control over the panel.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response! The component itself actually toggle open and closed without having to manually manage it. I understand that you can set an onClick action listener, then toggle it open or closed. I actually found out the problem, I'll post in a second. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why this answer is down-voted, I think its due to misunderstanding. I realized afterwards that it's effectively the same answer as mine. +1

Answer (score -2):

The problem here is that the keys that are on the `<Grid item ... />` elements in the `<Grid container />` parent view are not changing.

When a search is executed with a different type, the same data is being displayed, just displayed differently.

From my understanding, if react sees the same key with the same data, it doesn't need to re-render, even if there are states being passed as props to the children. In my case states are being passed as props to children in a `<Grid item ... />`.

As a resolution, I append the type of search to the key. So now when the search type changes, the key that holds the result does as well, and the children of the `<Grid item ... />` are triggered to be re-rendered.

Sorry for not the best explanation, I have some practical experience with ReactJS, but I can not speak about it that well from an "under the hood" point of view.

Comment: That's basically what my answer was getting at; you can't use `defaultExpanded` since the components aren't being re-rendered. However, forcing React to re-render the components isn't an ideal solution as it will reduce performance and impact the users' experience. `expanded` would be the better option and a bit simpler, unless you also need to allow those panels to be expanded/collapsed by the user, in which case you would need to add some additional logic.